# Is adding a Masking layer before the prediction layers correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to us a pre-trained model to classify images. Every image can have multiple classes (in this case up to 21). Of course not all classes occur in every image. Therefore, I want to add a `Masking` layer to the model which masks all zeros (given value if a class doesn't exist).

Now I've never used a `Masking` layer before, but in most online examples it is added directly after the `Input` layer. This is, however, not possible in the example below, because the `Masking` layer is not compatible with all layers (in this case a `Conv2D` layer.

It was possible to insert the `Masking` layer before the fully-connected output layer. But this did not really affect the loss of the model (**loss is around 20!**).

Am I doing it right or is adding the `Masking` layer at the top of the model totally useless?

**My Model**

```
from keras.layers import Input, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Masking, Dense, Dropout
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.models import Model

#Define input tensor
input_tensor = Input(shape=(512, 512, 3))

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a Mask fully-connected layer and a dropout
x = Masking(0.)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
# and a logistic layer with 21 classes
predictions = Dense(21, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# create final model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

**Example labels**

```
# input
np.array([[1,2,0,0,0,6,7,8,0,0,0,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
          [0,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,0,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]])
```

Comment: masking is very similar to padding, in your code it is ensuring that your dense layer is getting same sized input. Masking will not help in learning any this. Masking(0.) means you are making you input by 0.

Comment: Could you describe what is the purpose of the masking? What is a shape of a single mask?

Comment: I want a model which predicts if a class 1-21 occurs in an image. If a class does not occur it is labeled 0. These zeros cause imbalance in my dataset so I don't want the model to train on them. I thought that masking zeros would be away to fix this.

Comment: You might have better luck with the ML question of "how to deal with the "imbalance"" on stats.stackexchange.com. Having said that, I am actually quite curious, what "imbalance" you are referring to. If you don't want your network to learn about "non-classes", can you just make the loss function ignore the differences from expected and actual values for non-classes?

Comment: Also, I noticed in your input example, that you are using number 21 to represent the 21st class. You might want to just put a 1 in the input array when the corresponding class is present. This will make presence/absence of any class be represented the same way. With current scheme, you are likely giving more importance to predicting class 21 than to predicting class 1.